# How do I configure my web server to work with the PluggableAuthService's Domain Auth Plugin?

Tags: apache, nginx, plone, zope

I'm trying to use the Domain Auth Plugin to assign the Membership role to site visitors based on their IP address.

I can configure the plugin OK, but it occurs to me all the requests will be coming from localhost and not the "real" IP address.

In this case I'm using NGINX, so I tried setting X-Real-IP to $remote_addr via proxy_set_header (e.g. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule), but as far as I can tell that just makes the IP address available in the header.

How do I make the requests sent from NGINX to Plone appear to be originating from the remote IP address?

I'm using NGINX but I'm open to answers that apply to Apache too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Domain Auth Plugin uses the `request.getClientAddr()` method to determine the IP address of the client, which in turn uses both the `REMOTE_ADDR` variable and the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header.

Normally, you cannot rely on the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header, seeing as just about anyone could have set it. But you can configure Zope to trust that header from a given set of trusted proxies. Using the list of trusted proxies, the `REMOTE_ADDR` IP address will be replaced with the next address given in the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header, until you run out of addresses to trust. The last IP address found is then the new client address. This allows you to chain a set of proxies and still be able to trust you get the correct client address to base your roles on.

To configure Zope to trust a proxy's `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header, set the `trusted-proxy` configuration parameter in the `zope.conf` file. If your nginx server runs on the same host, just set it to localhost:

```
trusted-proxy 127.0.0.1
```

You specify more than one name by adding multiple entries:

```
trusted-proxy 127.0.0.1
trusted-proxy loadbalancer.localnet
```

`trusted-proxy` takes both ip addresses and hostnames.

Comment: Thanks Martijn! And as Rok Garbas pointed out to me privately, I also need to do this in my NGINX config: proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for.

Comment: Hi Martijn, are you sure you can put more than one entry? I my trusted-proxy line has "delivery2 delivery" and it refuses to start. "delivery2 192.168.1.10" refuses to start too...

Comment: @gforcada: Then again, I may have misremembered how a multikey is used; perhaps it should be `trusted-proxy 127.0.0.1` newline `trusted-proxy loadbalancer.localnet`. If so, my apologies.

Comment: @gforcada: Ick, confirmed my error; multikeys are repeated, not space-separated.

Comment: Adding a quick note, in case someone walks into the same edge-case I did: if you happen to use collective.usernamelogger < 1.3, the monkey patch of ZServer's logging is a regression of this feature (so use >= 1.4).

Answer (score 0):

Many reverse proxies set an X-Forwarded-For header to the original IP. The domain auth plugin should be updated to handle this if it doesn't already.

Comment: It doesn't need to handle the X-Forwarded-For header, Zope does this for you if you set the trusted-proxy configuration variable. :-)